# Reload the fragment in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, reload

I am building an android application where on click of add button an viewdailog box is open an in there is an fom fill by the user.

I need is that on click of ok button of that viewdailog box my fragment should be reloaded as user has added the vaules.

Here is the method that I am using in viewDialog box - \

```
private void viewCategory() {

        AlertDialog.Builder viewDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        viewDialog.setTitle("add");

        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)     
        getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View dialogView = li.inflate(R.layout.customealertdialogbox1, null);
        viewDialog.setView(dialogView);

        viewDialog.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        name = edt1.getText().toString();
                        address = edt2.getText().toString();
                        city = edt3.getText().toString();
                        phone = edt4.getText().toString();
                        //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        new DownloadJSON().execute();

                    }
                });

        viewDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                    }
                });
        viewDialog.show();

        edt1 = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.editbox1);
        edt2 = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.editbox2);
        edt3 = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.editbox3);
        edt4 = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.editbox4);
 }
```

Comment: you have refresh your fragment after adding values...

Comment: Yes, I need to refresh my fragment on adding the value.

Comment: no i need an method! that I asking you. I know where to reloaded it . But How can I do it

Comment: @Sonam Refresh means on your OK button click your AsyncTask is executing.

Comment: @Sonam For refresh your current fragment you need to first detach it from Activity after then attach to activity.

Comment: @PiyushGupta how can I do this

Comment: @Sonam When you refresh your fragment before that asynctask execution is completed?

Answer (score 1):

```
Fragment frg = new FirstFragment();
FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.detach(frg);
ft.attach(frg);
ft.addToBackStack(FirstFragment.class.getSimpleName());
ft.commit();
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65066/discussion-on-answer-by-nap-reload-the-fragment-in-android).